# Is possible to censor videos automatically?

Tags: python, django, video, video-processing, video-encoding

I'm creating a video sharing site using django, it's now using phpmotion but I decided to rewrite the script.

Users come to my site and upload spams and adult videos, i hate that. Is it possible to censor videos automatically? Using python, because i will soon remove phpmotion.

I'm pretty sure that this is impossible but, maybe you know about some way to do it automatically. Youtube censors Barclays football premier league games and occasionally some music videos, I don't know if it does that automatically but i guess not.

Comment: I once read an article about detecting nipples in videos, but can't seem to find it anymore. Maybe you can get something done by using OpenCV or something similar

Comment: You're asking about screening, not censoring. AFAIK YouTube screens videos by comparing them to disallowed content. Upload a porn stash and compare incoming videos to it.

Comment: @Juhana how to do screening? what python libraries should be used for that? i've never heard about the concept of screening before

Comment: [Screening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screening)

Comment: Screening is what you describe in your question. Censoring would be something like adding black boxes on private parts or beeps instead of swear words.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/youtube-vs-fair-use.html) is an article on CodingHorror about how Google detects copyrighted content in YouTube videos. Not directly applicable to your situation, but an example of automatic content analysis for videos.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sir, you gave me a list of topics about screening in medicine and biology, security films etc... I want to know about screening in computing, especially in video sharing websites, and how could that be done in python or ffmpeg or whatever library

Comment: Screening has *absolutely nothing* to do with programming; it is a manual process.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if it has nothing to do with programming then i should ask the community to report the vids. But I'm trying to detect them automatically as soon as they are uploaded.

Comment: @Juhana i don't want to add black boxes or beeps, i just want to delete videos that violate my policy

Comment: @RussellZahniser thank you so much, very informative article, but i need some written codes :)

Comment: *I know.* That's why I'm trying to tell you what the correct term is. Nitpicking, sure, but it should help googling/asking for the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you're taking the wrong approach to this problem. Are your users required to log in to post a video? Perhaps new users should have all their videos on a "needs to be approved" list before they will appear on the site, and regular users can have theirs go live immediately. Put a "Flag Content" button below each video so users can self-moderate as well.

Comment: @Mark perhaps you are right :D

Comment: Even if there are algorithms and methods to do this, implement them in pure python will kill performance.

Comment: @Dikei what programming language do you believe is best for these methodes?

Comment: I have no idea of how to do it, but if I were to implement one, I would choose something fast like C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether you understand German or not, but this article might be useful:

http://www.linux-magazin.de/Heft-Abo/Ausgaben/2011/07/Objekterkennung

They have done some amazing things with opencv and show how to detect naked bodies - if it's the adult content you're worrying about.